# Using isomorphic-fetch with systemjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, systemjs

How to properly load `isomorphic-fetch` with `systemjs` module loader. I am building a npm package that can be used both on browser and node applications.

I've installed isomorphic-fetch with es6 promises,

`npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise`

My current `systemjs.config.js`

```
var map = {
   'app':                        './js', // 'dist',
    ... 
    ...
    'isomorphic-fetch' : './node_modules/isomorphic-fetch'
};

var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js'},
    'isomorphic-fetch': { defaultExtension:'js'}
};

var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages,
};

System.config(config);
```

When I try to load this on the browser, I get a `Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <(…)` on the require line.

Comment: That looks like your server may be returning a HTML response (beginning with <) instead of a script. Try having a look in the network tab in your devtools.

Comment: @HenrikKarlsson When I change the packages path for isomorphic-fetch to     ```'isomorphic-fetch': { main:'fetch-npm-browserify', defaultExtension:'js'}</code></pre>```, ` it works on the browser, but how can I make it dynamic so that `fetch-npm-node` is used when I use this package in node app.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but I think this might be what you are looking for if you are on .17: http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/conditional-loading.html

Comment: thanks @HenrikKarlsson. I am not using JSPM atm, but I will explore to see if it can be achieved with SystemJS and npm.